# Linux serial console works with earlyprintk=ttyS1, but not with console=ttyS1

Tags: linux, console, serial-port

I have a server with its secondary UART (ttyS1) connected via USB to a laptop (at `/dev/ttyUSB10`).

If I boot Linux on the server with

`console=ttyS1,115200n8 earlyprintk=ttyS1,115200n8`

I can see the kernel output on the serial console (`minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB10` on the laptop). However, if I only specify

`console=ttyS1,115200n8`

It doesn't show anything anymore.

I ask this because I am not able to get a login shell as well with the first one!

My kernel have all the necessary serial configs enabled, amongst them

```
CONFIG_SERIAL_EARLYCON=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
```

Do you have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I enabled the following kernel options.

```
SERIAL_8250_16550A_VARIANTS=y
SERIAL_DEV_CTRL_TTYPORT=y
TTY_PRINTK=y
```

Also make you sure you have compiled the keyboard drivers for input.